# RESTSharp Max post Size

Tags: c#, json, restsharp

We are currently using:

```
request.JsonSerializer = new RestSharpJsonNetSerializer(jsonSerializer);
```

to serialize our `JSON POST request`. Our JSON is approximately `4.5MB` when created. It appears that when the JSON is serialized it is getting truncated therefore it is failing when it gets to our API endpoint.

Is there is a way to set the max size of a JSON POST for `RestSharp`?